# DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH with current Mac OS X is not working?

Tags: java, macos, dyld, java.library.path

my goal is to make the jodbc driver from sybase working with my gradle build. But the `System/bin64/sa_config.sh` is not working as expected. This script modifies/ appends the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (see extraction of script):

```
# comment the following to unset the SA location.
SQLANY11="/Applications/SQLAnywhere11/System"
export SQLANY11

# comment the following lines to remove SA binaries from your path.
PATH="$SQLANY11/bin64:$SQLANY11/bin32:${PATH:-}"
export PATH
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY11/lib32:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$SQLANY11/lib64:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:-}"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

But the libraries inside the `lib64` directories can't be found.

To have a easier check what happenes I tried the [example code from chilkatsoft](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-MacOSX.asp). The sybase script uses the possibility 3. I changed the script of chilkatsoft library to check if I can load the chilkasoft driver. But the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH definition is not working (other options like `-Djava.library.path="path/to/library"` are working with this little example).

I added a subdirectory `myTestDir` which includes my test script, because the jnilib is always searched at root directory. This is my test script:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -version
javac -encoding utf8 -classpath ".:./chilkat.jar" Test.java
BASE_PATH="/Users/Wagner/Desktop/testLIB/chilkatJava-9.5.0-jdk6-macosx/"

echo "################## TEST: with environment variables ########################"
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BASE_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

java -classpath ".:./chilkat.jar" Test

echo "################## TEST: with absolut path at -Djava.library.path ########################"
java -Djava.library.path=$BASE_PATH -classpath ".:./chilkat.jar" Test

echo "################## TEST: with realative path at -Djava.library.path ########################"
java -Djava.library.path=.. -classpath ".:./chilkat.jar" Test
```

This shows the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not added to `java.library.path`and it is not working. But using directly the `java.library.path` is successful. See output:

```
myTestDir  ./myTest.sh
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
################## TEST: with environment variables ########################
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/Wagner/Desktop/testLIB/chilkatJava-9.5.0-jdk6-macosx/
***** INFOS *****
java.library.path=/Users/Wagner/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
***** LOAD LIBRARY *****
Native code library failed to load.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no chilkat in java.library.path
################## TEST: with absolut path at -Djava.library.path ########################
***** INFOS *****
java.library.path=/Users/Wagner/Desktop/testLIB/chilkatJava-9.5.0-jdk6-macosx/
***** LOAD LIBRARY *****
***** LIBRARY LOADED *****
9.5.0.56
################## TEST: with realative path at -Djava.library.path ########################
***** INFOS *****
java.library.path=..
***** LOAD LIBRARY *****
***** LIBRARY LOADED *****
9.5.0.56
Wagner  ... | testLIB | chilkatJava-9.5.0-jdk6-macosx | myTestDir
```

I'm using the current Mac OS X version with all updates (10.11.5). Do someone have a idea to make this work with `DYLD_LIBRARY:PATH`??

Thanks in advance and best regards, Oli

Comment: I can't help, but my ImageMagick installation seems to have stopped working as a result of upgrading to OS X 10.11.5. I know the behaviour of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is related to System Integrity Protection, so I think Apple have changed something in 10.11.5. Very annoying